# Intellij Windows Terminal as terminal (in ide)

Tags: windows, intellij-idea, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I use WSL with Ubuntu 18.04.

In Intellij i want to change terminal to Windows Terminal (or Ubuntu Terminal), but when I add `wt.exe` as shell path (File -> Settings -> Tools -> Terminal), ide returns new window with Windows Terminal (not on the bottom of ide).

I also used Windows Terminal.exe path, but it doesn't work.

```
C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\Microsoft.WindowsTerminal_8wekyb3d8bbwe/wt.exe
```

Comment: Just type in 'wsl.exe' and your wsl configured linux-shell appears.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can't use GUI app as the terminal shell in IntelliJ IDEA, use the command line app like `cmd.exe`, `powershell.exe` or `c:\Windows\System32\bash.exe`.

Answer (score 12):

Now you can use WSL terminal inside the IDE by just using the `wsl.exe` string in the terminal settings of your IntelliJ IDEA as the [documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/settings-tools-terminal.html) describes:

**Shell path**
Specify the shell that will run by default. Here are some examples of different shells:

- Bash: /bin/bash
- Z shell: /bin/zsh
- Bash for Windows: bash.exe
- WSL: wsl.exe
- PowerShell: powershell
- Command Prompt: cmd.exe
- Cygwin: "C:\cygwin\bin\bash.exe" --login -i